# Android - Convert arrayList to String []

Tags: java, android, string

Bom dia pessoal, preciso converter um `ArrayList` para uma `String[]`.

Não consegui fazer funcionar. Somente me retorna uma string gigante. Segue meu código

```
public List<Item> geral(){
    buscaLatLong();
    List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] namesArr = nomes.toArray(new String[resuladoLista.size()]);

    List<Item> item = new ArrayList<>();
    String listagem[] = namesArr;



    for (int i = 0; i<listagem.length; i++){
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setNome(listagem[i]);
        item.setNum(String.valueOf(i+1));
        itemList.add(item);
    }

    return itemList;
}
```

Fiz um teste com uma `String` fixa no formato abaixo funcionou perfeitamente

```
 String listagem[] = {"Teste1",
                "Teste2",
                "Teste3",
                "Teste4"};
```

O resultado lista está como `private static ArrayList resuladoLista`;
Como posso converter o meu `resuladoLista` para uma string idêntica ao `listagem[]`?

Comment: Seja bem vindo, coloque na pergunta como está instanciado o `resuladoLista`.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Tente com a classe `ArrayUtils` da seguinte forma

```
String[] fruitsArr = ArrayUtils.toStringArray(fruitsList);
```